# Powershell iterate through list<string> returned from c# class library

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a powershell script that calls a c# library (.net framework) and returns a list or IEnumerable, I have tried both.

```
    $scriptPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    $dir = Split-Path $scriptPath
    $dllPath = $dir + "\MyCacheTools.dll"

    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllPath)

    $files = [MyCacheTools.CacheTools]::DirSearch($cachePath))

    ForEach ($file in  $files) {
      Write-Output $file
     }
```

C#

```
    public class CacheTools
    {
         public static IEnumerable<string> DirSearch(string path)
         {
             var t = GetFiles(path);
             return t;
         }

         static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path)
         {
             Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();
             queue.Enqueue(path);
             while (queue.Count > 0)
             {
                 path = queue.Dequeue();
                 try
                 {
                     foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories     (path))
                     {
                         queue.Enqueue(subDir);
                     }
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
                 }

                 DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(path);

                 FileInfo[] files = null;
                 try
                 {
                     files = source.GetFiles();
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
                 }

                 if (files != null)
                 {
                     for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                     {
                        yield return files[i].Name;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

I am having issues iterating through the list that is returned.

I would really appreciated a hand.

Windows 10, powershell 5.1

(edit)
The issue I was having was that it appeared nothing was being returned. $files displayed nothing. I was running it in the visual studio console and we seeing results. As it turns out, for my system, I had to run it in admin mode. I wasn't seeing the error in powershell ISE

Comment: What happens if you debug the code in PowerShell ISE? What's the value of `$list`? What's of `$list | gm`, `$list.gettype()` etc? P.S. Consider NET4 DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos as it's not blocking and provides the first result immediately.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean with "having issues" exactly?

Comment: I just ran your code and it works perfectly for me, i.e., it prints all the file names. What exactly is the 'issue' ?

Comment: The problem was that I had to run PowerShell ISE as admin.

Comment: The reason I did not use DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos was that I assume that if it failed on one directory (permissions maybe) then the entire process would fail. But I do like the suggestion.